# Vue and Laravel separate app - Need feedback on architecture

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need a bit of expert feedback on this please as I do not want to start my project in the wrong way.

I would like to keep my Vue code separated from Laravel, the reason being, I may use this vue app later on on Cordova.

**First question:**
I understand how to host the Laravel API and Vue app on 2 different domains, no problems at all but I am unsure on how to setup the folder when both apps are on the same domain.
I know that Laravel should be hosted below the public_html folder and have a symlink to the public folder for security purpose. But where should my vue app goes?

**Second question:**
When I save images from Vue(as I am creating a blog) the images are going to the Laravel store/images folder, so each time I want to show an article in my vue app, the API must each time request the content(text and images) from the Laravel API, is this fine? Will the Google bot be able to trigger the API request when requesting the content?(I actually never thought of this...)

Thank you so much!

Comment: A few days ago I separated my laravel-vue app into 2 repositories. My api is hosted on api.domain.com and vue is on my.domain.com. It is working very well and development is much easier. I think that host your api on a subdomain is a good practice. You should only expose api endpoints from your laravel app.

I store my static files (images, pdf etc.) on a s3 bucket. You need to get the verified url from backend and you can display it on frontend. Google bot also can check these images.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, very much appreciated. I started to do the same but I am having a problem and I would love to know how you deal with it. I presume that you are using the Laravel passport, where and how do you save your token? If the client side data can be accessed easily by hackers, how to protect this side of the project? Thanks

Comment: You should store your token in cookie (client side). If you setup correctly the cookie's attributes then the hackers can't steal it. (Required attributes: secure, httpOnly, SameSite). You should send this cookie in authorization header to your backend in every request. If you use axios then you can setup an interceptor which append this header all of your requests. Here you can get more info about cookie attributes: https://www.paladion.net/blogs/cookie-attributes-and-their-importance

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is very useful to know. I will give it a shot shot tomorrow.

Comment: I checked further the issue but here is where I am stuck. It looks like httponly can only be set from the server side and not client side as it stops Javascript from accessing it. How would you store the cookie client side via http only and then send that cookie back in the header(if it cannot be read by Javascript). Thank you. Remember, the API and vue app may be on 2 different domains.

Comment: Passport now makes that relatively easy to set up:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Install and configure Passport as per the normal instructions, add the `HasApiTokens` trait the to User, and add the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to `$middlewareGroups` in app\Http\Kernel. Set the driver to 'passport' for the api guard in config/auth.php

Comment: Yes this is what I did, I separated vue from Laravel and used the passport. The main problem is the use of an axios inceptor to get a new token when the old one expired, that was not an easy job.